# Clicking on form button without an <input>?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am trying to click on the "Slow Download" button on [this](http://nitroflare.com/view/A71F0994E20F2E0/security-privacy.jpg) page, where the html is

```
<form action="https://nitroflare.com/view/A71F0994E20F2E0/security-privacy.jpg" method="post">
   <button id="slow-download" class="bootstrapButton" name="goToFreePage">Slow Download</button>
</form>
```

where I am doing

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function   startFreeDownload(){
  getElementsById('slow-download')[0].submit();​
};
startFreeDownload();
});
```

All the posts I have seen have `<input ... >` which this one doesn't.

**Question**

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the problem.

```
function SkipId(objId){
    var oId = document.getElementById(objId);
    oId.click();
}

window.onload = function(){
    SkipId('slow-download');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to submit a button, but should submit a form instead:

```
...
getElementsById('slow-download').parent()[0].submit();​
...
```

Comment: Very interesting. It doesn't submit/clicks when I replace it with your code.